# Can I use std::stop_source to deferred cancel all worker threads from a worker thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

I have two threads running in parallell started from the main thread.
Either thread may fail. If it do so I want to ask the other thread to cancel as well.
In C++ 20 there is `std::stop_token` and `std::stop_source`.
I have found several examples where the main thread ask all threads to cancel (deferred cancelation).
However I have not found any examples where either worker thread may deferred cancel all other worker threads.
How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for a location of code to be able to request a stop, that location must have a `std::stop_source`. In order for a location of code to be able to respond to the stop, it must have a `std::stop_token` taken from a particular `stop_source`.

Therefore, in order for a location of code to be able to both request and respond to a stop, it must have *both* the `stop_source` and the `stop_token`.

Now, since `stop_source`s are able to generate `stop_token`s, there's no reason why you can't just give the thread function a `stop_source` and have it extract a token from it. Of course, this won't be able to use `std::jthread`s convenience ability to detect that a thread function whose first argument is a `stop_token` and generate a `stop_source`, but the nature of your stopping needs wouldn't make that viable anyway.

Also, remember that `stop_source` is *copyable*; the copies all share the same internal stop-state (along with any `stop_token`s created from them). So there's no reason to pass them by reference.